# Create an Apple Automation to notify power cuts when at home

Tags: power, automation, homekit

I have some electrical noise at home, and would like to use test equipment to verify its absence during power outages.

I’d like to be notified when my power at home goes out, but I cannot find an easy way to script this. I have iOS devices (iPhone, iPad, HomePod) and assorted HomeKit automation equipment (bulbs, sockets). I have plenty on ancillary kit (Pi, Windows PCs, components etc).

The standard automation triggers which might be useful are for WiFi networks, but only when you connect, not disconnect. Likewise, charger disconnect triggers seem to go off when charging finishes and the charge cycle stops - which is not necessarily a power outage.

I would ideally like to know, day or night, when my home power goes out (which is likely to also affect the nearby noise source). I only care about reviving this notification when at home, and do not mind the odd false positive.

Can anyone provide inspiration for an approach please?

Comment: What do you have that's monitoring the power supply?  When the power goes out, anything that can notify you needs to be on battery power and be able to monitor the power supply, like a battery backup unit.

Comment: If you need to test something with the power off, why not just switch the power off?

Comment: @fsb - I have the things listed. I want to use them to trigger a notification. I understand that the thing doing the notifying will need to operate on battery. Logically then, a battery-powered iOS device needs to understand that the power is out, using (lack of?) connection to one of the others perhaps?

Comment: @Tetsujin - it’s not me causing the interference, but it is within a small number of houses.